# How do I pass a value between classes in tkinter?

Tags: python, class, variables, tkinter

I have created a ten question multiple choice quiz in Tkinter/Python. I have created a class to store all the buttons and then ten other classes to store each question which appears in a child window with the question as a label and radiobuttons / checkbuttons. For each question, when the user presses 'Enter' the program will compare their selection to the correct answerer and add 1 point to score where necessary. How do I make the variable 'Score' available to everything in the program (i.e. every single class)? And do I have to pass the value of score between classes?

```
class Question_5_Window(tk.Toplevel):
    '''A simple instruction window'''
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.text = tk.Label(self, width=100, height=4, text = "5) What would you do if you were walking to class and you saw a first year crying? Tick all correct answers.")
        self.text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        question_5_Var1 = IntVar()
        question_5_Var2 = IntVar()
        question_5_Var3 = IntVar()

        A_5 = Checkbutton(self, text = "Keep walking", variable = question_5_Var1, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=5, width = 20)
        A_5.pack()

        B_5 = Checkbutton(self, text = "Take them to guidance", variable = question_5_Var2, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=5, width = 20)
        B_5.pack()

        C_5 = Checkbutton(self, text = "Talk to them to resolve issue", variable = question_5_Var3, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=5, width = 20)
        C_5.pack()

        def calculate_score():

            if (question_5_Var2.get() == 1) and (question_5_Var3.get() == 1) and not question_5_Var1.get():
                print("calculate score has worked")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("not worked")

            return score

        Enter_5 = Button(self, text= "Enter", width=10, command = calculate_score)
        Enter_5.pack()

        return score
```

Comment: Do you have any example code?

Comment: @user3056786 I think this is going to take some discussion / revision / edits. Anyone who wants to help, maybe you can use [this chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43338/how-do-i-pass-a-value-between-classes-in-tkinter).

Comment: @user3056786 Please accept the answer if it worked for you or update what didn't work so this question can be resolved. If you want your question to be helpful for other people with a similar problem to yours, you might like to update your question to follow the guidelines we discussed.

Comment: Yes, the solution you gave DID work

Answer (score 4):

Based on our discussion, the quickest way to get what you want is to add an attribute to your tk object that contains your question buttons.

```
class WhateverContainer(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self)  # ... *args, **kwargs or whatever is appropriate
        # ... other stuff
        self.scores = dict()  # common storage

class Question(tk.TopLevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, question_id):  # ... whatever arguments
        # ...
        def callback()
            if nice_answer:
                parent.scores[question_id] = 1
```

To be clear, this is not a "good" solution since at the least, the child windows should not be messing directly with the data of the parent. However, I think it will work for your application. If you would like to get feedback on your design and coding, you might have some luck on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

I hope the quiz works well for you.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to accomplish this is to declare a Tkinter control variable (an IntVar in your case, since it's handling the quiz score) in your main module, and then make this same control variable an attribute of each class that needs to share/update it.  When you do this, every class can use the get/set methods of the IntVar and all their updates carry through to the other classes (and the main module).

I wrote a short demo program I call "tripwire" to prove to myself that this works:

```
import Tkinter as tk

#Clumsy thief who crosses the tripwire
#The twVar is a Tkinter IntVar
class Thief1:
    def __init__(self,twVar):
        self.twVar = twVar

    def cross(self):
        self.twVar.set(1)

#Second thief who silences the alarm
#The twVar here is the same one as Thief1
class Thief2:
    def __init__(self,twVar):
        self.twVar = twVar

    def silence(self):
        self.twVar.set(0)

#Main module
root = tk.Tk()

#Declare and initialize the IntVar
ctrlTW = tk.IntVar()
ctrlTW.set(0)

#Instantiate each class, using the same
#IntVar for each
t1 = Thief1(ctrlTW)
t2 = Thief2(ctrlTW)

#Now call each thief's method
print 'Initial value:  '+str(ctrlTW.get())
t1.cross()
print 'After Thief #1: '+str(ctrlTW.get())
t2.silence()
print 'After Thief #2: '+str(ctrlTW.get())
```

A cool side benefit of this technique is that you can use the control variable's observer to execute a callback whenever any of the classes does something with the value.  This (partly) addresses KobeJohn's concerns about having the child window messing with the parent's data.  The callback allows the main module to at least monitor what each class is doing with the shared data and react accordingly.

```
#Main module with trace and callback added
root = tk.Tk()

def twObserve(*args):
    if (ctrlTW.get()):
        print 'Hey! Intruder detected!'
    else:
        print 'Oh... never mind.'

#Declare and initialize the IntVar
ctrlTW = tk.IntVar()
ctrlTW.set(0)

#Set the callback for updates
ctrlTW.trace('w',twObserve)

#Instantiate each class, using the same
#IntVar for each
t1 = Thief1(ctrlTW)
t2 = Thief2(ctrlTW)

#Now call each thief's method. The callback
#will activate with each update.
t1.cross()
t2.silence()
```